# Get child item using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have categories and subcategories and I return data in Stored procedure like:

```
  SELECT
                 [RC].[Name] AS 'CategoryName'
                , [RS].[Name] AS 'SubcategoryName'
                 FROM [RedMarkCategory] AS [RC]
                     INNER JOIN [RedMarkSubcategory] AS [RS] ON [RC].[RedMarkCategoryId] = [RS].[RedMarkCategoryId]
                     WHERE RS.IsDeleted = 0
            ORDER BY
                   [RC].[Name]
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

As you can see one category can have multiple subcategories.

So in c# I first get Categories to create `GroupBoxes` dinamically and inside GroupBox I want to create `Checkboxes` foreach subcategorie :

```
DataTable dataFromDb = GetData();

            string[] distinctCetgories = dataFromDb.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(x => x.Field<string>("CategoryName")).Distinct().ToArray();


    

foreach (var itm in distinctCetgories)
        {
            // extract all the subcategories for the checkboxes inside the groupbox
            string[] subcategories = dataFromDb.AsEnumerable().
                Where(x => x.Field<string>("SubcategoryName") == itm).
                Select(y => y.Field<string>("SubcategoryName")).ToArray();

            flpRedMarks.Controls.Add(GetGroupBox(itm, subcategories, 200, 100));
        }
```

Categories are created successfull but  subcategorie query is allways 0:

```
string[] subcategories = dataFromDb.AsEnumerable().
                    Where(x => x.Field<string>("SubcategoryName") == itm).
                    Select(y => y.Field<string>("SubcategoryName")).ToArray();
```

So I always get empty checkboxes:

[image]

What is wrong with my query? Regards

Comment: I believe you want to use CategoryName in the where clause of your subquery

Comment: Group by `CategoryName`, and then for each group you get the subcategories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe in here you wanted to filter subcategories based on category name. But instead your where clause is comparing with `SubcategoryName`

So instead of

```
string[] subcategories = dataFromDb.AsEnumerable().
                Where(x => x.Field<string>("SubcategoryName") == itm).
                Select(y => y.Field<string>("SubcategoryName")).ToArray();
```

It should actually be

```
 string[] subcategories = dataFromDb.AsEnumerable().
                Where(x => x.Field<string>("CategoryName") == itm).
                Select(y => y.Field<string>("SubcategoryName")).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, Group by `CategoryName`, and then for each group you get the subcategories.

That way everything can be done in one pass.

For example

```
var categories = dataFromDb.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(_ => _.Field<string>("CategoryName"))
    .Select(g => new {
        CategoryName = g.Key,
        SubCategories = g.Select(_ => _.Field<string>("SubcategoryName"))
    });


foreach (var category in categories) {
    var name = category.CategoryName;

    //...Create GroupBox
    var groupBox = new GroupBox() {
        Text = name
    };

    //...

    foreach (var subcategoryName in category.SubCategories) {

        //...Create CheckBbox with subcategoryName and add to groupbox

        var checkBox = new CheckBox();
        checkBox.Text = subcategoryName;

        //...

        groupBox.Controls.Add(checkBox);
    }

    //...do something with groupbox
}
```